# Perform actions such as median, mean, etc. on certain unique values ​from a particular column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
animals = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['Dog','Cat','Snake','Snake','Dog','Hamster','Cat','Alligator','Cat','Cat','Dog','Hamster','Alligator'],
                 'age':[2,1,5,7,5,1,4,15,6,9,3,2,40],
                  'weight':[10,4,3,20,15,0.1,6,300,7.1,10,12,0.15,350],
                 'length':[1,0.45,1,2,1.2,0.16,0.40,4.8,0.45,0.50,0.49,0.14,5]})
```

Suppose I have such a data frame
and I want to find out let's say what the average weight of cats is.
How can this be done?

Comment: It looks like you need `animals.groupby('animal').describe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html). It's similar to what you'd do with SQL.

```
animals.groupby('animal').mean().loc['Cat', 'weight']
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot!